# Which is a better method of designing an upcounter in verilog from the ones mentioned below?

Tags: verilog, synthesis

I have declared an 8 bit register variable **count**

```
reg [7:0]count=0;
```

**count** is supposed to increment from **8'h00** to **8'hFF** & back to 8'h00 & increment again so on.
Below i am providing 2 ways of doing this

```
always @(posedge Clk)  
   begin  
      if(count==8'hFF)  
         count<=8'h0;  
      else  
         count<=count+1;  
   end
```

OR

```
always @(posedge Clk)  
   begin  
     count<=count+1;  
   end
```

In the 1st case, **count** will go from 00 to FF & 00 to FF again & again.
In the 2nd case also, **count** will go from 00 to FF then overflow to 00 with a carry & increment to FF again & again.

Will that carry affect anything & how? Also which method is better synthesis wise?

Comment: My guess is that `count<=count+1;` in the both cases results in the same adder structure. And if you are unlucky the upper example also adds a comparator to check if `count` equals `ff` along with a reset for `count`. But I would say, do synthesis and compare! The carry out will be removed or dangling - no harm.

Comment: The code is part of a larger code. I am using Dsp48 & all. So will that carry from count overflow affect other part of code?

Comment: I'm just guessing here: no. Count is just 8 bit, and you are not mentioning the carry out in the code, so it will not get connected to anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either method will work. The best result is dependent on the how smart/dump your synthesizing tool is. Some tools issue warnings when it sees an overflow is possible. If you want to resolve the warning, you can use the below method:

```
reg [7:0] count = 0;
wire [8:0] next_count = count + 1'b1; // MSB is overflow bit
always @(posedge Clk)
  count <= next_count[7:0]; // overflow bit not used in assignment
```

The overflow bit could be done in the synchronous block. Unless you plan on using the overflow bit, I would not recommend these as it will either waste a flop (dumb synthesizer) or issue a warning that a flop has been optimized out (smart synthesizer).

```
reg [7:0] count = 0;
reg overflow;
always @(posedge Clk)
  {overflow,count} <= count + 1'b1; // optimization warning OR wasted flop
```

Comment: `count <= count + 1'b1;` does not give a warning in XST. No need to explicitly mention the overflow bit.

Comment: @Moberg, Different tools are more or less picky. I have used tools that do give warnings when overflow is not explicitly handled, and I prefer to keep the warning list as short as possible.

Comment: Yeha, I understand that tools differ, thats why I mentioned that this was the behaviour of XST. But yes I agree with keeping the warnings away. And for this sake it can be better to always explicitly handle the overflow in case you switch tool or the tool changes.

Answer (score 1):

According to IEEE Std 1364™-2005

> should an arithmetic add of two 16-bit values perform the evaluation using 16 bits, or should the evaluation use 17 bits in order to allow for a possible carry overflow? The answer depends on the type of device being modeled and whether that device handles carry overflow. The Verilog HDL uses the bit length of the operands to determine how manybits to use while evaluating an expression. The bit length rules are given in 5.4.1. In the case of the addition operator, the bit length of the largest operand, including the lefthand side of an assignment, shall be used

They have given an example which I think is applicable for this case:

```
reg[15:0] a, b; // 16-bit regs
reg[15:0] sumA; // 16-bit reg
reg[16:0] sumB; // 17-bit reg
sumA = a + b; // expression evaluates using 16 bits
sumB = a + b; // expression evaluates using 17 bits
```

So, hopefully it won't affect the synthesis and is better than previous one.